# Is there any knowledge/experience how performFetchWithCompletionHandler's completion value affects future scheduling?

Tags: ios

The documentation for performFetchWithCompletionHandler only has this to say about the completion values:

> pass in the fetch result value that best describes the results of
>   your download operation

That's all it says, nothing else. Nothing about the consequences of returning one value instead of another.

Does anybody have any experimental or anecdotal observations regarding how these values affect the future scheduling of performFetchWithCompletionHandler?

For example I was wondering if by occassionally returning a failed value it might result in the OS re-scheduling performFetchWithCompletionHandler to run more often then it might do if newData was returned.